# Toggle do JQuery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Eu estou utilizando a função *toggle* do *jQuery*, está funcionando perfeitamente, porém eu coloquei 12 *divs* com texto e quando eu clico em abrir somente uma, todas estão abrindo.

Segue o código do *JavaScript*:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span.seta-baixo").click(function(){
        $("p.perguntas-conteudo").toggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

O que eu quero é o seguinte, quando eu clicar em uma *div*, vai expandir o texto somente dela e quando eu abrir a outra *div* com outra informação de texto, vai fechar a anterior e abrir somente essa.

O que está acontecendo é que ao clicar no botão para abrir o texto, abre todas as *div*, ou seja, o *toggle* está pegando em todas.

Comment: cara edita a pergunta e cloca tb seu código HTML, vai facilitar pra te responder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar o índice da classe da seta clicada e aplicar o `.toggle` no respectivo índice da classe `.perguntas-conteudo`, já que cada seta corresponde a um `p`, então cada índice da classe da seta `.seta-baixo` corresponde ao mesmo índice da classe do `p` `.perguntas-conteudo`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span.seta-baixo").click(function(){
        // pega o índice da seta clicada dentro da classe
        var idx = $(this).index(".seta-baixo");
        // pega o respectivo <p> pelo índice usando :eq
        var per = $("p.perguntas-conteudo:eq("+idx+")");
        // oculta todos os <p> visíveis exceto o relacionado à seta clicada
        $("p.perguntas-conteudo:visible").not(per).hide();
        // abre ou esconde o respectivo <p> da seta
        per.toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.seta-baixo{
   display: block;
}

.perguntas-conteudo{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <span class="seta-baixo"><strong>Seta 1</strong></span>
   <p class="perguntas-conteudo">pergunta 1</p>
   <span class="seta-baixo"><strong>Seta 2</strong></span>
   <p class="perguntas-conteudo">pergunta 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu! Muito Obrigado